# Relation query in Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

This is a basic question, but I can't understand how the relationship works in Parse.

I have this relationship: [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPztQ.jpg)

Briefly, it is a relationship 1 - N. One FeedPost have several comments.

I wish I can send the post ID in the Query and just get the araylist of comments on that post.

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> innerQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comments");
    innerQuery.whereExists("UXKFwWyn3l"); //ID of the post
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("FeedPost");
    query.whereMatchesQuery("objectId", innerQuery);
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

With this line

```
innerQuery.whereExists("UXKFwWyn3l");
```

you are saying "all records that have a value in the column 'UXKFwWyn3l'"

Also, you are using PFRelation when you should rather use pointers. In Comment, you should have a column with a pointer to the FeedPost. If you did, this query would get you the comments you want, providing you have the FeedPost object already:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comments");    
query.whereEqualTo("post", thePostObject );
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> comments, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // "comments" is now a list of the comments
        } else {
            // Something went wrong...
        }
    }
});
```

You can also have a reverse relationship in FeedPost, which should be an array of pointers to the comments (not a PFRelation). If you do, you can get both the FeedPost and the comments with one query:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("FeedPost");
query.include("comments"); // this is the column with an array of pointers to comments
query.getInBackground("UXKFwWyn3l", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject feedPost, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // Your feedPost now has an array with all the comments
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

You should only use PFRelation for advanced relations (like many-to-many).

Comment: I have another problem... query.whereEqualTo("Post", "LX5IiOGvq3"); isn't work... The second options isn't util for me, I need request a arraylist.

Comment: If all you have is the ID of the post, you will need to create a post using that ID (bare-bones object, enough to be used for the pointer). Look here: https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#createWithoutData(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Use the actual Post *object*, not the objectId. There is no reason you should have the id and not the object itself. I can't see many usecases where you would work with the actual objectIds like that, although they exist. In most cases, you have the Post object. Your problem is related to a test case, not a real use case.